# Jenkins manual Trigger for successful build

Tags: ant, triggers, jenkins

I need help with Jenkins.

I want trigger over an button in the already successful builded 'build' page (where the testresults, artefacts etc. are listed) one target in an ant script.

Is that possible over an plugin or do I have there to do more?

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I can see you can get at the moment.

A combination of the Jenkins [Batch Task Plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:jenkins.io%20Batch%20Task%20Plugin):

> This plugin adds batch tasks that are not regularly executed to
> projects, such as releases, integration, archiving, etc. In this way,
> anyone in the project team can execute them in a way that leaves a
> record.

and [Sidebar-Link Plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:jenkins.io%20Sidebar%20Link%20Plugin):

> This simple plugin adds an Additional Sidebar Links section in the
> main Jenkins configuration page, with settings for link URLs, texts
> and icons. These links will be shown in the top-level Jenkins pages
> (main page, user list, build history, My Projects and other project
> view tabs). Sidebar links for particular jobs may also be added in the
> job configuration pages.

You can use the Sidebar-Link Plugin to add these to the project page, but it *doesn't* appear to support adding it to the build page as of yet - might be worth raising a JIRA ticket and requesting this as it was part of the [original ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8600?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab#issue-tabs).

In the Batch Task Plugin you can define a task - that might well be an Ant invocation - this example is called 'release'.

[image]

Then you can run the task from the web interface:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jenkins-ci.org](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/3309627/task-top.png?version=1&modificationDate=1192707321000))</sub>

And records of these post-build tasks are kept and accessible:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jenkins-ci.org](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/3309627/task-builds.png?version=1&modificationDate=1192707321000))</sub>

Comment: But can't I put such a task also in the page from the build? When I click on an successful build I want there an new button for such an trigger.

Comment: @Tommy - Somehow I missed that part of your question - apologies.  It seems *nearly* possible - see revised post.